# How to set image placement around a textblock

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm new to C# and wpf so please don't criticize if this is a dumb question.

I have Image and TextBlock inside a DockPanel, then I have a ComboBox which controls where the image would appear around the text. ComboBox items are ("left of text", "right of text", "above the text", "below the text", "center")

I was able to do left, right, top, and bottom by binding DockPanel.Dock but for the center, I need to put the image behind the text (overlaying them) and DockPanel doesn't allow me to do that. I wanted to use Canvas but I was specifically asked not to for a different reason (textwrapping problem, etc.)

Now I just really need to overlay the image and text when "center" is selected from combobox.

xaml

```
<DockPanel>
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="{Binding Path=ImagePlacementDisplay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

view model

```
    public string SelectedImagePlacement
    {
        get { return _ex2.ImagePlacement; }
        set
        {
            _ex2.ImagePlacement = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedImagePlacement");
            OnPropertyChanged("ImagePlacementDisplay");
        }
    }

    public string ImagePlacementDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            switch (SelectedImagePlacement)
            {
                case "0": 
                    return "Left";
                case "1": 
                    return "Right";
                case "2":
                    return "Top";
                case "3":
                    return "Bottom";
                case "4":
                    return "Center"; //not working
                default:
                    return "Right";
            }
        }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("ImagePlacementDisplay");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to show xaml. The z-order is same as order of panel children, put `Image` first, then `TextBox` and the latter will be *above*. Or you can use [ZIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5450985/1997232) to change it.

Comment: @Sinatr I included snippets of my code but I'm not sure if it helped or it just made my question more confusing. I tried using Panel.ZIndex but it wasn't just what I wanted.

Comment: So you want both controls to [occupy the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28356153/1997232) and overlap? You can make an own panel with custom enum to control alignment. Or you can forget about `DockPanel`, use `Grid` and arrange controls using data triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data triggers to modify control position.

Below is 2x2 `Grid` and depending on `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` value the data trigger will arrange location of `Image` (simulated with yellow grid) and `TextBlock`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Background="Yellow">
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=combobox}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="1" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=combobox}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="1" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=combobox}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=combobox}" Value="3">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=combobox}" Value="4">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Bla bla bla" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=combobox}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="1" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=combobox}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="1" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=combobox}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=combobox}" Value="3">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=combobox}" Value="4">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <ComboBox x:Name="combobox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Left"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Right"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Up"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Down"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Center"/>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Demo:

[image]

It may not be the best looking solution, but it demonstrates the power of data triggers and maybe teach you a bit of layouting (very important skill in wpf).

A better approach would be to create custom `Panel` with custom dependency property of enum type to control children arrangement.

Comment: Thank you for providing an alternative. But this approach is hardwired to UI and will be difficult to maintain if I make some changes. I still need to add Margin (a numeric box controls this) between them, a frame for the text, etc. So I'm guessing I need to try making a custom Panel just like you said.